# spring task:scheduled-tasks default scheduler pool size

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks

We are using spring's task:scheduled-tasks to schedules one task based on cron expression. Our basic config looks like this. My question is, since we are not providing reference to scheduler to "task:scheduled-tasks", how does is work? What kind of default configuraiton it generates automatically?

```
<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="runScheduler" method="run"
        cron="0 0/5 * * * ?" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fore more information on your example [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-and-spring-taskscheduler-example/) based on your example.

All information is explained into this article.

But to resume, into your configuration:

```
<task:scheduled-tasks>
<task:scheduled ref="runScheduler" method="run"
    cron="0 0/5 * * * ?" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

Into "*task:scheduled*" you have a "*ref*" attribute that reference the bean **RunScheduler**.
It can declare by:

- XML configuration file, in this example into this file "*resources/spring/batch/jobs/job-report*":

  `<bean id="runScheduler" class="com.mkyong.RunScheduler" />`
- Annotation:

  @Component

  public class RunScheduler {

  ```
  ...
  ```

  }

Comment: Thanks Sinouplen. But my question is more around configuring "scheduler" in this tag <task:scheduled-tasks>" which is basically a thread pool. So if you don't provide any then how that default pool look like. In terms of scheduled-tasks, it is working fine for me.

Comment: If you use Spring Integration module, the default scheduler is **`SimpleTaskScheduler`**.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **Spring Integration**, the default task scheduler is [explain here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/archive/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/apbs03.html).
It's a *`SimpleTaskScheduler`*.